# Get data from input using template literals as id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a program that makes a table using json data. This technique uses template liretals, so i can add rows myself however i want. My problem is that I need to get data from an input, which has a template literal as an id, but the getElementById doesn't allow me to.

I have already tried escaping my brackets, but that doesn't work. I have looked into using a simple index, but i don't know how I could set it up in my function.

Here is the javascript code:

```
//load JSON file
var articles = ""
var txt = ""
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    articles = xmlhttp.responseText;
    txt = JSON.parse(articles);

    processArticles(txt);

    processForm(txt);

  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","../articles.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();

function processArticles(txt) {

  var tableStart = `
    <h2>Liste des articles</h2>
    <form id="formtable">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Prix</th>
        <th>Prix-Retour</th>
        <th>Quantitée maximale</th>
        <th>Projet</th>
        <th>Quantitée</th>
      </tr>`;

  var tableEnd = `
    </table>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>`;

  function articlesTemplate(txt, index) {
      return `
          <tr>
            <td>${txt.ID}</td>
            <td>${txt.Article }</td>
            <td>${txt.Prix}</td>
            <td>${txt.PrixRetour}</td>
            <td>${txt.QuantiteeMaximale}</td>
            <td>${txt.Projet}</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="quantity${txt.ID}" id="quantity${txt.ID}" min="1" max="5"></td>
          </tr>
      `;

  }


  let mctxt=txt.filter(value=>
    value.Projet=="mc");
    document.getElementById("tablemc").innerHTML = `
      ${tableStart}
      ${mctxt.map(articlesTemplate).join("")}
      ${tableEnd}
      `;
    ;
}
```

The problem is in the .getElementById of my quantity in this last function.

```
function processForm(txt) {
  var form = document.getElementById('formtable');
  var quantity = document.getElementById(`"quantity$\\{txt.ID\\}"`);

  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("HI");
   console.log(quantity.value);
 };

}
```

I want to be able to collect the quantity of each object selected and also the price of that same object, so that i can make a total price at the end of the table.

Comment: That string interpolation is not good, try: ``getElementById(`quantity${txt.ID}`);``.

Comment: I get this error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null``` It seems as if it can't find the template literal

Comment: u are adding id as string, it is not dynamic... u need use backticks instead double quotes and than it should work as expected

Comment: open up ur dev tools u will see that all id are the same.

Comment: **Please show the result of `JSON.parse(articles)`.**

Comment: The html is being rendered ok? Does `articlesTemplate` works?

Comment: my articlesTemplate work, as i can see my table

Comment: This is what i get when i log txt : ```0:
Article: "Baguette de bois de 1/4"" x 1/4"""
ID: "1"
Prix: "2.00"
PrixRetour: "1.00"
Projet: "mc"
QuantiteeMaximale: "5"
__proto__: Object
1:
Article: "Baguette de bois de 3/8"" x 3/8"""
ID: "2"
Prix: "1.79"
PrixRetour: "0.90"
Projet: "mc"
QuantiteeMaximale: "10"
__proto__: Object
2:
Article: "Baguette de bois de 1/2"" x 1/2"""
ID: "3"
Prix: "2.00"
PrixRetour: "1.00"
Projet: "hp"
QuantiteeMaximale: "5"
__proto__: Object
length: 3``` I don't think txt is the problem, as the lements get displayed in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you accidentally did bad quoting like @DontVoteMeDown already mentioned.

Lets assume

```
txt.ID = 2
```

then the template string

```
`<input ... id="quantity${txt.ID}" />`
```

will result in

```
<input ... id="quantity2" />
```

as well as the selector's template string

```
document.getElementById(`quantity${txt.ID}`);
```

will result in

```
document.getElementById("quantity2");
```

So it should work in general.

If you want to **sum all input values** of the resulting table, you have to select **all** inputs and iterate over the values.

```
var total = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('#formtable input').forEach(function(input) {
   total += parseInt(input.value);
})
```

Comment: Even when i copy paste your line, it gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLFormElement.form.onsubmit. Do i need to include something in the function for it to work? Maybe have it in the same fucntion as articlesTemplate?

Comment: On a second look I noticed you are using the variable `txt` multiple times. First in a plural-context `processArticles` then `processForm` as singular context. Maybe u missed out `txt` contains an `Array`?

Comment: oh that could very much be the case, i am still new to javascript so i'm not really sure how the function elements work. Do you know how i could fix this?

Comment: It then may be a design problem. Your function `processForm` can only deal with **one** element of your Array, while your function `processArticles` can deal with the Array itself. If you want to "collect" the values of ALL inputs, you will again have to select **multiple** elements and iterate over the result

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that or would i have to remake my whole script?

Comment: Just edited my answer. I think it would help you in understanding the situation.

Comment: When i write this code at the end of my script i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).map is not a function and also i can't add them all up because i need to multiply each quantity by the price. I think i will delete this code and write it in ajax, because it seems to handle indexes much better and there are a lot more tutorials on it

Comment: sorry, I forgot NodeList needs `forEach` while Array has `map()`. Updated the code.